# How to export filtered list data to Excel

Tags: excel, custom-list

I have custom application page. There are few datepickers, to filter custom list data. When user clicks on Export To Excel ( which is asp:Button ) I need to filter data based on datepickers value, and write it in Excel file, and return file to client. How can I achieve this ? I saw that one of the options is to export SPGridView data to excel, but when I'm using this approach, everytime I'm opening excel file I'm getting warning popup.

Comment: did you find the answer to this question yet?? Let me know if you do.. Thanks

Comment: I think Michael is referencing this link? http://www.fivenumber.com/export-spgridview-to-excel-spreadsheet-in-sharepoint-2007/

Comment: @Subbu Hi, yeah I found a workaround, as I did use EPPlus open source project to generate Excel files, the question ( maybe not well formed ) was about how this can be easily done via SP, couldn't find anything so far, that's why didn't update the post.